# What is the correct way to query in mongodb for the array of documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The following is the collection in the mongodb

```
{
"name" : "Tom" ,
"occupation" : "employee" ,
"data" : [
        {
            "owns" : "Television" ,
            "company" : "xyz"   
        },
        {
            "owns" : "Television" ,
            "company" : "abc"   
        },
        {
            "owns" : "laptop" ,
            "company" : "abc"
        } ,
        {
            "owns" : "Television" ,
            "company" : "xyz"
        }

        ]   
}
```

when I query

```
   db.exp.find({"data.owns" : "Television"})
```

mongodb returns the document which has "owns" :"laptop" in the result set.

when I query

```
   db.exp.find({"data.owns": "Television"},{_id: 0, data: {$elemMatch: {"owns": "Television"}}})
```

the result only displays one document from data field where first match of "Television" is found

How do I query to get all 3 documents where Tom owns Television excluding laptop document. 
Expected result

```
 [
        {
            "owns" : "Television" ,
            "company" : "xyz"   
        },
        {
            "owns" : "Television" ,
            "company" : "abc"   
        },

        {
            "owns" : "Television" ,
            "company" : "xyz"
        }

 ]
```

Note: I mentioned only 4 documents in the data field in this example, where as the original collection has more than 50 documents. 
sorry for my poor english :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the [**aggregation.**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db-collection-aggregate)

- [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) the `data` array.
- Use [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) stage to filter document where `owns` value is `Television`.
- The [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage to re-group your document.
- The [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage to reshape your document.

```js
db.exp.aggregate(
    [
        { "$unwind": "$data" }, 
        { "$match": { "data.owns": "Television" }}, 
        {
            "$group": {
                          "_id": {
                                     "name": "$name",
                                     "occupation": "$occupation"
                                 }, 
                          "data": { "$push": "$data" }
                      }
        }, 
        {
            "$project": {
                            "name": "$_id.name", 
                            "occupation": "$_id.occupation", 
                            "data": 1, 
                            "_id": 0
                        }
        }
    ]
)
```

**Result:**

```js
{
        "data" : [
                {
                        "owns" : "Television",
                        "company" : "xyz"
                },
                {
                        "owns" : "Television",
                        "company" : "abc"
                },
                {
                        "owns" : "Television",
                        "company" : "xyz"
                }
        ],
        "name" : "Tom",
        "occupation" : "employee"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have two documents in the collection `exp`

```
[
  {
  "name" : "Tom" ,
  "occupation" : "employee" ,
  "data" : [ { "owns" : "Television" , "company" : "xyz" },
    { "owns" : "Television" , "company" : "abc" },
    { "owns" : "laptop" , "company" : "abc" } ,
    { "owns" : "Television" , "company" : "xyz" } ]   
  },
  {
  "name" : "Jerry" ,
  "occupation" : "employee" ,
  "data" : [ { "owns" : "Mobile" , "company" : "xyz" },
    { "owns" : "Mobile" , "company" : "abc" },
    { "owns" : "laptop" , "company" : "abc" } ,
    { "owns" : "Laptop" , "company" : "xyz" } ]   
  }
]
```

Then with your query `db.exp.find({"data.owns" : "Television"})`, you will get

```
{ "_id" : 101, 
"name" : "Tom", 
"occupation" : "employee", 
"data" : [ 
  { "owns" : "Television", "company" : "xyz" }, 
  { "owns" : "Television", "company" : "abc" }, 
  { "owns" : "laptop", "company" : "abc" }, 
  { "owns" : "Television", "company" : "xyz" } 
 ] 
}
```

As the first document has the fields `owns` equal to `Television`, the result will be complete first document.(including those fields that have `owns` other than `Television`)
The second document will not be part of the result, as it doesn't have any `owns` fields with the value `Television`.

`$elemMatch` will only return one document.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

If you only want those three objects inside the array which have `Television` as its value, then you can use a cursor to store the entire result(in our case only one document) of the query.

```
var x = db.authors.find({"data.owns": "Television"},{_id: 0, "data.owns": 1})
```

And now, use for each loop to get only the documents that have `owns` with the value `Television`.

Comment: instead of filtering the documents in the external application, aren't we able to do this task in the database itself?

Comment: You can use aggregation for this purpose. Sorry, that i didn't mention in the answer.